# LINQ: converting a query expression to use lambdas

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm trying to rewrite a LINQ To Entities query to an expression.  My model is a School which can have many Persons. Persons are inherited out to teachers, students, etc.

The following query works for me:

```
IQueryable<DAL.TEACHER> teacher = 
from p in School 
select p.PERSON as ESBDAL.TEACHER;
```

How would I write this as a query expression?  I thought something like:

```
IQueryable<DAL.TEACHER> teacher = 
School.Select(x=>x.PERSON) as IQueryable<DAL.TEACHER>;
```

Unfortunately this statement doesn't work.  Am I misunderstanding the `.Select()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should actually be:

```
School.Select(x => x.PERSON as DAL.TEACHER)
```

Remember, you're trying to cast the `PERSON` to a `TEACHER`, so it goes *inside* the delegate.  The result of `School.Select(x => x.PERSON)` by itself is actually an `IEnumerable<PERSON>`, which is not convertible to `IEnumerable<TEACHER>`.

One more thing - if some `PERSON` instances are not actually `TEACHER`s (i.e. they are `STUDENT`s instead), you're going to end up with `null` references in the output.  If `PERSON` can be more than one type, you would probably want to write it out like this instead:

```
School.Select(x => x.PERSON).OfType<DAL.TEACHER>();
```

This will actually filter out all of the `PERSON` entities that *aren't* `TEACHER`s, so you only get back `TEACHER` instances in the sequence (no nulls).

Also note that the `from x in y` syntax is the "query" (specifically *query comprehension syntax*).  The second form is lambda syntax.